# Is there a way to invert collision detection in unity?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, .net

I'm trying to make a drag and drop tool to make maps in my game (dungeon crawl). I would like to use colliders to define geometry, just invert the case so that collisions are good, not colliding is bad. Does Unity do this in a nice way or do I have to build from the ground up?

Ideally, I would like a player to be constrained by a CompositeCollider2D.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is actually how Unity's collision system already works. I had thought from using it before that a box would just push out another box, but it seems to simply be 4 edges in a box shape. I would highly recommend this structure (CompositeCollider2D) for making a 2D collision map.